# [INFO]Payment method on personal website without e-commerce CMS

Tags: php, html, paypal, content-management-system, credit-card

I'm developing a website full in php and html without using any cms. I would like to add to my personal website a payment method. I found that i could add paypal code for doing this but i would like to know if there is something else for paying on my website using credit cards or bank transfer.

Can you give me some suggestions about it ?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: i'm sorry that i didn't specified before, but i'm developing it in Italy, i don't know if there is some sort of problems with regions compativility....

Comment: I've choosen the best answer for me, so now the question could be close. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[Stripe](https://stripe.com/)** - there is a small processing fee but it's extremely simple to use and free to set up. I have built many-a-website recently with this payment system. I personally prefer it over PayPal. However, if you go the PayPal route, use Payments Pro (there is a first-time charge and then transaction/processing fees).

Edit - I just read the recent comment from OP about being in Italy. Stripe is not available in Italy yet, but looking at all the countries that are in BETA, I'd be willing to assume that Italy isn't far behind. With that said, you are better off using a brand of PayPal or Google Merchant since they have much better international support. However, sign up for notifications on Stripe in Italy. You'll hate all other processing systems once you make your first transaction with Stripe. :)

Comment: Thank you, i saw that stripe is very cheaper than paypal ! the only took fees on buying andnot monthly .... hope they will support italy as soon as possible :P

Answer (score 0):

[Stripe](https://stripe.com) is a good alternative to PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Google Checkout?  Whatever you use, you just want to make sure its secure and your not storing any credit card info on your own site.

There are plenty of options out there, but what payment processing methods are your users use to?  I like PayPal because most of my users know all about PayPal and already have accounts with them - so they already 'trust it'.    Other services might be fine, but if the user doesn't know about that service and/or trust them - they might be less likely to use it for payment.

just my two cents.